# PHP ini_set not setting 'error_log' custom log file path correctly

Tags: php, php-ini

So I'm trying to basically set up in my initialization file some code that allows error displaying on my localhost/development mode and does not allow error displaying on my network solutions server/production mode. Ive removed the if else statement as I'm currently testing this on my localhost server, so i'm assuming that you are as well. Here's the code:

```
// Set INI to log errors
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
// Set Error Log Path Variable (Grabs the Root Directory of the Project, then appends on the path)
$errorPath = dirname(substr(dirname(__FILE__),strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))) . '/logs/php/error.log';
// Set INI for error_log path
ini_set('error_log', $errorPath);
// Give some code thats going to throw an error
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=a;dbname=test", "root", "");
```

`$errorPath` contains:

```
string(36) "/OOP Login System/logs/php/error.log"
```

That is the correct file path, with "OOP Login System" being the "root" directory. The "OOP Login System" folder is currently sitting in my htdocs folder within my Apache Server.

Now my app is throwing a "Uncaught PDOException" which is great! I want that. But what its not doing is saving that error into my error.log file. Just curious as to how to go about this. Any reason why its not saving? I have created the error.log file in the php folder, and tried to run again, but its still not working.

Very new to working with PHP's ini, so any help would be great. Sorry in advance if you reply and i still have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: You should inspect `$errorPath` (if you don't have a debugger, just `var_dump($errorPath);` it). There's also `phpinfo()` to see actual directive values.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I did a var dump on $errorPath and got the following. Posted it in a pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/GSxSQD7Q

Comment: Pastebin? Why? How much output can it possibly generate? Plus I don't know what your file system looks like.

Comment: The vardump returns a string of the filepath, and it is correct.

Correct File Path with "OOP Login System" being the "application root" directory. (/OOP Login System/logs/php/error.log) The "OOP Login System" folder is currently sitting in my htdocs folder (server root) within my Apache Server.

The var_dump() gave me this: `string(36) "/OOP Login System/logs/php/error.log"`

Comment: Is "OOP Login System" really in two locations, the root directory and some htdocs subdirectory? That's possible (you can create links in all major operating systems) but I suspect it isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but…
I guess the problem resides in this line:

```
$errorPath = dirname(substr(dirname(__FILE__),strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))) . '/logs/php/error.log';
```

That produces this invalid path:

```
\/logs/php/error.log
```

You should use

```
$errorPath = basename(substr(dirname(__FILE__),strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))) . '/logs/php/error.log';
```